# How to get these shapes to line up for a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to input vectors into a numpy matrix by doing:

```
eigvec[:,i] = null
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,1) into shape (20)
```

I've tried using `flatten` and `reshape`, but nothing seems to work

Comment: What does `eigvec.shape` gives you?

Comment: Also, what is `null` defined as? It is not a Python keyword.

Comment: null is the nullspace of A- lambda*I it should have 20 entries

Comment: Based on your error, my guess is `null` is defined somewhere as an array of shape (20, 1), possibly containing `0`s or smth. I'm not sure how you used `flatten` but `eigvec[:, i] = a.flatten()` should work if `a` is has shape (20, 1) and `eigvec` has shape (20, 20).

Comment: @Chris: what is `null.shape`?

Answer (score 1):

I can guess that

```
eigvec[:,i] = null.flat
```

would work (however, `null.flatten()` should work too). In fact, it looks like NumPy complains because of you are assigning a pseudo-1D array (shape (20, 1)) to a 1D array which is considered to be oriented differently (shape (1, 20), if you wish).

Another solution would be:

```
eigvec[:,i] = null.T
```

where you properly transpose the "vector" `null`.

The fundamental point here is that NumPy has "broadcasting" rules for converting between arrays with different numbers of dimensions. In the case of conversions between 2D and 1D, a 1D array of size n is broadcast into a 2D array of shape (1, n) (and not (n, 1)). More generally, missing dimensions are added to the *left* of the original dimensions.

The observed error message basically said that shapes (20,) and (20, 1) are not compatible: this is because (20,) becomes (1, 20) (and not (20, 1)). In fact, one is a column matrix, while the other is a row matrix.

Comment: As the error message states, the shape of the target for the assignment is (20), not (20, 1). The rest is correct, though.

Comment: I am not sure I am following you: I am not saying that the target *has* shape (20, 1): I am saying that NumPy assigns "to a 1D array"—so, not 2D with shape (20, 1). I also imply that, while one could think that this 20-elements 1D array could be automatically converted to shape (20, 1), it is actually *considered by NumPy* to be of shape (1, 20), hence the error message (and the `null.T` solution).

Comment: I just thought your original wording was a bit confusing, but your edits are much clearer (I upvoted your original answer anyway)

Answer (score 1):

The shapes in the error message are a good clue.

```
In [161]: x = np.zeros((10,10))

In [162]: x[:,1] = np.ones((1,10))  # or x[:,1] = np.ones(10)

In [163]: x[:,1] = np.ones((10,1))
...
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,1) into shape (10)
In [166]: x[:,1].shape
Out[166]: (10,)
In [167]: x[:,[1]].shape
Out[167]: (10, 1)

In [168]: x[:,[1]] = np.ones((10,1))
```

When the shape of the destination matches the shape of the new value, the copy works.  It also works in some cases where the new value can be 'broadcasted' to fit.  But it does not try more general reshaping.  Also note that indexing with a scalar reduces the dimension.